# This is Iphone Device Crash Log Help me to debug this

Tags: iphone

```
       Any one help to debug this Crash Log
```

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000001, 0xe7ffdefe
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x30064430 0x30060000 + 17456
1   Foundation                      0x32235230 0x32229000 + 49712
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3050611e 0x304e7000 + 127262
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30504b5c 0x304e7000 + 121692
4   Foundation                      0x322351e0 0x32229000 + 49632
5   Foundation                      0x322367cc 0x32229000 + 55244
6   Quadmon                         0x0000553e 0x1000 + 17726
7   CoreFoundation                  0x305304c8 0x304e7000 + 300232
8   UIKit                           0x35be00e0 0x35b6f000 + 463072
9   UIKit                           0x35be0048 0x35b6f000 + 462920
10  UIKit                           0x35be0010 0x35b6f000 + 462864
11  UIKit                           0x35bdfc60 0x35b6f000 + 461920
12  UIKit                           0x35be04ec 0x35b6f000 + 464108
13  UIKit                           0x35bde538 0x35b6f000 + 455992
14  UIKit                           0x35bddb6c 0x35b6f000 + 453484
15  UIKit                           0x35bd8318 0x35b6f000 + 430872
16  UIKit                           0x35bd7a94 0x35b6f000 + 428692
17  GraphicsServices                0x32763d64 0x3275e000 + 23908
18  CoreFoundation                  0x3051cf28 0x304e7000 + 220968
19  CoreFoundation                  0x3051cee6 0x304e7000 + 220902
20  CoreFoundation                  0x3050f182 0x304e7000 + 164226
21  CoreFoundation                  0x3050ee58 0x304e7000 + 163416
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3050ed66 0x304e7000 + 163174
23  GraphicsServices                0x32762e0c 0x3275e000 + 19980
24  UIKit                           0x35b7673c 0x35b6f000 + 30524
25  UIKit                           0x35b74994 0x35b6f000 + 22932
26  Quadmon                         0x000044d2 0x1000 + 13522
27  Quadmon                         0x00002d94 0x1000 + 7572

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31b8fca4 0x31b5a000 + 220324
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31c5e520 0x31b5a000 + 1066272
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31c5df8c 0x31b5a000 + 1064844
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31c5d9ac 0x31b5a000 + 1063340
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be6bd8 0x31b5a000 + 576472
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31bdd564 0x31b5a000 + 537956

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31b5b6e0 0x31b5a000 + 5856
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31b5dbc4 0x31b5a000 + 15300
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3050f8d0 0x304e7000 + 166096
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3050f0d4 0x304e7000 + 164052
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3050ee58 0x304e7000 + 163416
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3050ed66 0x304e7000 + 163174
6   WebCore                         0x3637c24c 0x36379000 + 12876
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be5dac 0x31b5a000 + 572844
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31bd7a0c 0x31b5a000 + 514572

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be47b4 0x31b5a000 + 567220
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31b912a0 0x31b5a000 + 225952
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31b90c40 0x31b5a000 + 224320
3   CoreMedia                       0x30942ca0 0x3093e000 + 19616
4   CoreMedia                       0x30942b7c 0x3093e000 + 19324
5   MediaToolbox                    0x3363dd14 0x33638000 + 23828
6   CoreMedia                       0x3096fb90 0x3093e000 + 203664
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be5dac 0x31b5a000 + 572844
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31bd7a0c 0x31b5a000 + 514572

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31b5b6e0 0x31b5a000 + 5856
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31b5dbc4 0x31b5a000 + 15300
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3050f8d0 0x304e7000 + 166096
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3050f0d4 0x304e7000 + 164052
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3050ee58 0x304e7000 + 163416
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3050ed66 0x304e7000 + 163174
6   Foundation                      0x32256c4e 0x32229000 + 187470
7   Foundation                      0x32234b8a 0x32229000 + 48010
8   Foundation                      0x3222db90 0x32229000 + 19344
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be5dac 0x31b5a000 + 572844
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x31bd7a0c 0x31b5a000 + 514572

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31b84c08 0x31b5a000 + 175112
1   CoreFoundation                  0x30548518 0x304e7000 + 398616
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be5dac 0x31b5a000 + 572844
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31bd7a0c 0x31b5a000 + 514572

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be7564 0x31b5a000 + 578916
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be6db8 0x31b5a000 + 576952
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31bdd564 0x31b5a000 + 537956

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be7564 0x31b5a000 + 578916
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31be6db8 0x31b5a000 + 576952
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31bdd564 0x31b5a000 + 537956

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x0018c4b0    r1: 0x338885b6      r2: 0x321dc138      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x001d8c41    r5: 0x00000000      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x2fdfce04
    r8: 0x00000030    r9: 0x0000b5d4     r10: 0x2fdfcf56     r11: 0x2fdfcf3c
    ip: 0x3e3bc568    sp: 0x2fdfcde8      lr: 0x32235237      pc: 0x30064430
  cpsr: 0x000f0010

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x4efff +Quadmon armv6   /var/mobile/Applications/B86D9649-CB4B-429A-9AE1-D1ECD99D67ED/Quadmon.app/Quadmon
   0xfc000 -    0xfdfff  dns.so armv6  <74c285bd895a96cff24cfc3105162d59> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
 0x31e8000 -  0x31ebfff +libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib armv6   /Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib
 0x3400000 -  0x3513fff  RawCamera armv6  <90c10fbb9eba333944ca52cee579d03c> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe29fff  dyld armv6   /usr/lib/dyld
0x30005000 - 0x3000afff  libGFXShared.dylib armv6  <0fa46082a915cbb03a848dd28f9154b4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x30048000 - 0x3004dfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv6  <1222b2e280ee4571371b378bca9adda4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x30054000 - 0x30057fff  CertUI armv6  <616f89f165e5567812774bde6f787a32> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30058000 - 0x3005ffff  liblockdown.dylib armv6  <799adeedf5a3c7061ab4fe7e684b7407> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x30060000 - 0x30127fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv6  <19602777bafcb74a32e691273d49a620> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x30199000 - 0x301a5fff  libkxld.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x301ac000 - 0x301bcfff  Search armv6  <02f5fa77720fbbe97f119458ddb3c7d1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Search.framework/Search
0x301bd000 - 0x301fffff  CoreTelephony armv6  <3df7d35a6666e1b74121ce918304dec6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x3030f000 - 0x3031bfff  WebBookmarks armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3031c000 - 0x3043dfff  MusicLibrary armv6  <4b8e77f43ccc38ab6e77758b3197347c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x3044d000 - 0x304affff  GMM armv6  <55ebf8664ad7d52bb74e6b07fcfd3c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x304e7000 - 0x305c2fff  CoreFoundation armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30692000 - 0x3069dfff  ITSync armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x306a2000 - 0x306e9fff  VideoToolbox armv6  <84fbf0e4ce3a7d2c44cdc8d243ec7087> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x306ea000 - 0x307d6fff  QuartzCore armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x30817000 - 0x3084dfff  IMFoundation armv6  <2634bdc62d2533fa07e465ccbba0263d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x3084e000 - 0x3085efff  PrintKit armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x30884000 - 0x3089dfff  libcupslite.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libcupslite.dylib
0x308d5000 - 0x3093dfff  libvDSP.dylib armv6  <2cd0e06f601bc2d6e42a60cf4e37a3b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3093e000 - 0x309b7fff  CoreMedia armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x309b8000 - 0x30b8afff  AudioToolbox armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x30b93000 - 0x30c03fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv6  <8663cfe2d90da389f5979dec70c09d9a> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x30c0a000 - 0x30d90fff  CoreGraphics armv6  <1e3064fa470a7718be068bba76264cbf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x30da8000 - 0x30de6fff  ContentIndex armv6  <35d9aca444ea6dd3e323c1e8fea52c88> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x30de7000 - 0x30ea7fff  ImageIO armv6  <09915f6c7420e85e793ad47cb79ec6a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x30eac000 - 0x30fe2fff  MediaPlayer armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x30fe6000 - 0x30ff4fff  libz.1.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x30ff5000 - 0x30ffbfff  MobileKeyBag armv6  <702a13d52d251c5968a5715b1bdc1b0c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x31003000 - 0x31007fff  MobileIcons armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x3107e000 - 0x3109dfff  Bom armv6  <056fad66663fb4af6d6d853b1d1c73e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3109e000 - 0x31116fff  EventKit armv6  <9c028b1913e948b7291aeb5e54adf167> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x311a3000 - 0x311edfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x311ee000 - 0x312e4fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv6  <51ba12e21ea34351d17ab281ff30aac7> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x31732000 - 0x31732fff  Accelerate armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x31733000 - 0x3173efff  MobileWiFi armv6  <9fc9ab0b6311713dcb45d4eba0b825d7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x3179f000 - 0x318c6fff  PhotoLibrary armv6  <68139a8587dc018e100ba5d9e8099ee6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x318c7000 - 0x31966fff  ProofReader armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x31967000 - 0x3197dfff  PersistentConnection armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x319bd000 - 0x319cafff  CoreVideo armv6  <9c533b2e4cdfaf497f479b5937e240c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x319cb000 - 0x319d0fff  IOSurface armv6  <42c5e959122390b371865256b8213d7f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x319e4000 - 0x31b41fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv6  <80e4dbe0c1758b1759cbf3b466011b60> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x31b5a000 - 0x31c98fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31ce3000 - 0x31e1dfff  GameKitServices armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GameKitServices.framework/GameKitServices
0x31e1e000 - 0x31e31fff  libmis.dylib armv6  <3fc1895af6b027f3095564340e92892f> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x31e32000 - 0x32150fff  GeoServices armv6  <1f044242f1063aa0ada1997f6ea7a59c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x3215c000 - 0x32163fff  BluetoothManager armv6  <1f3f5e7b208a6874a670d0e52fb00908> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BluetoothManager.framework/BluetoothManager
0x321a6000 - 0x321edfff  ManagedConfiguration armv6  <6b444d29b00b55fc63a941cd94336a0e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x321ee000 - 0x32228fff  MobileCoreServices armv6  <86c4f7627b60d3fbc835a6b29c858076> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x32229000 - 0x3234afff  Foundation armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3234b000 - 0x3235dfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv6  <44332a1c2b175533743ec2179e57a070> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x3235e000 - 0x3237ffff  FTServices armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x32380000 - 0x3249afff  libicucore.A.dylib armv6  <7dac9bba92600900f8c948f2b74b7481> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x324a0000 - 0x324e3fff  SystemConfiguration armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x324e8000 - 0x325dcfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv6  <2faed3bce443211ad848a45f0509e223> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x3275e000 - 0x3276dfff  GraphicsServices armv6  <9ee06c32e8ea04a9c7f536c74ea704db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x327f1000 - 0x3284dfff  libGLImage.dylib armv6  <3f54653b6f0fa44abac662f4ce624b5a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x32862000 - 0x3288bfff  MobileSync armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x32897000 - 0x328a1fff  AccountSettings armv6  <8d78a97ad37ed9d777f285f688e22647> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x328a2000 - 0x32923fff  EventKitUI armv6  <4ecc98a450db0606fbf3952f7ddaf9ca> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKitUI.framework/EventKitUI
0x32926000 - 0x32a36fff  CFNetwork armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32a37000 - 0x32a3afff  ActorKit armv6  <5d634e637eb748406f20f3982393277d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x32a3d000 - 0x32b32fff  Celestial armv6  <65ba56608b21b03c4a61eff63ffdcddd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x32b33000 - 0x32b34fff  DataMigration armv6  <44af13241e57d0bedfd6040b96733a3d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x32b35000 - 0x32b3afff  CaptiveNetwork armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x32b3b000 - 0x32b3dfff  Camera armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Camera.framework/Camera
0x32bc1000 - 0x32bd0fff  OpenGLES armv6  <2f4b5e4ec8752df711adcac719787025> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32c06000 - 0x32c09fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv6  <8a6b5847d94eaafae5824338fb7ecd74> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x32c74000 - 0x32c74fff  vecLib armv6  <65362b55805c596fba5a749ce0772779> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32c75000 - 0x32c78fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x32ca0000 - 0x32cc6fff  MediaControl armv6  <4604f9a409a63f0baa48086089a006be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControl.framework/MediaControl
0x32dfd000 - 0x32dfefff  CoreSurface armv6  <1ebe2180251ee87fe5f5f977ea454a8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x32e46000 - 0x32e71fff  DataAccess armv6  <7b592fba3961cca2b16744c8732d6ce3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x32e72000 - 0x32eb7fff  ImageCapture armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
0x32eb8000 - 0x32ee6fff  MIME armv6  <4883c5fbcd1c7447edd52adc367fc931> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x32eed000 - 0x32f4efff  IMCore armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x32f53000 - 0x32f5ffff  SpringBoardServices armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x32f60000 - 0x32fcbfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv6  <93af563bb28fa1fd81dc8a1ea11cabc6> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32ff8000 - 0x32ffafff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv6  <88da9bc26f5298d335fe2b8814fc70f6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32ffb000 - 0x3300efff  Notes armv6  <9d630919cdffbb626145508cc8714bf6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x3305b000 - 0x3308dfff  AppSupport armv6  <9d9768ae2d3476df7039ba6ac5d5a451> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x330bd000 - 0x3311bfff  CoreAudio armv6  <9b7a97af75983afe8cc40c409a68b306> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x33130000 - 0x33141fff  DataAccessExpress armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x33142000 - 0x33157fff  TelephonyUI armv6  <5509b3f2194588b2449a8d76b0d77523> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x33185000 - 0x3318bfff  MBX2D armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MBX2D.framework/MBX2D
0x3318c000 - 0x331c2fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x33243000 - 0x33250fff  DataDetectorsCore armv6  <75b36158941950b5d70a8f7322032531> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x33251000 - 0x3325bfff  AggregateDictionary armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x33268000 - 0x332cefff  libBLAS.dylib armv6  <0fc1bc33e5274a252159482ca22fd3fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3338a000 - 0x3348afff  JavaScriptCore armv6  <05773ad92fcda46c93280fbf1e009029> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x33498000 - 0x334a5fff  MobileBluetooth armv6  <0b70bde6238f2e96f1d44d6cebefe3e8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x334a6000 - 0x335ebfff  libmecabra.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x335f5000 - 0x33614fff  EAP8021X armv6  <7a9a0d4157b2fdcc9bed141398be52af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x33634000 - 0x33637fff  ArtworkCache armv6  <61f7437ad1ca4fc5e5aa3745b20c216f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ArtworkCache.framework/ArtworkCache
0x33638000 - 0x3388bfff  MediaToolbox armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x338c1000 - 0x338ccfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv6  <2b22313336a93c991816019ba61e7d96> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x338cd000 - 0x338e1fff  MobileDeviceLink armv6  <04155f77f4272d19421830330971c089> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x338e2000 - 0x33935fff  IOKit armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33936000 - 0x3393afff  ApplePushService armv6  <626fb9c9cb2f3ec778f4df2d6fd02519> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3393c000 - 0x3393ffff  Marco armv6  <2472dd2996809e817f40ff52d576fa8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x33943000 - 0x33998fff  IMAVCore armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMAVCore.framework/IMAVCore
0x339bd000 - 0x33a07fff  Conference armv6  <4da298c6632c6840934aa6b38573babb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Conference.framework/Conference
0x33a14000 - 0x33abefff  AVFoundation armv6  <8f1cb3bcd5d935a57d6cf2950c33ecc1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x33ac6000 - 0x35b6efff  TextInput armv6  <5ce45546db26e46ae17d4e1911976738> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x35b6f000 - 0x35fdbfff  UIKit armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x35fdd000 - 0x360b8fff  WebKit armv6  <2eb09c7261a7695d3a4aa0335c1aabd6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x360b9000 - 0x36142fff  Message armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x361e3000 - 0x36203fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv6  <3c2573a10e032370516c85eab37ddfca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3630b000 - 0x3634afff  QuickLook armv6  <290457937afa6254547fc436e0cd08d6> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x36379000 - 0x36bc6fff  WebCore armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36bc7000 - 0x36cadfff  MapKit armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x36ccb000 - 0x36ce9fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x36d34000 - 0x37101fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x37102000 - 0x3712afff  StoreServices armv6  <5474f2a7ef4963d5cc5760960aa78e3f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x37134000 - 0x3713afff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv6   /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x3713b000 - 0x3713bfff  Spotlight armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Spotlight.framework/Spotlight
0x3714a000 - 0x37208fff  AddressBookUI armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x37216000 - 0x3725efff  iCalendar armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x3725f000 - 0x37262fff  CrashReporterSupport armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x3726c000 - 0x372bbfff  Security armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x37316000 - 0x3731efff  IAP armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x374f3000 - 0x3751efff  Preferences armv6  <62fcd8757107a40c6dca5c1b0759a7eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Preferences
0x3751f000 - 0x37579fff  MessageUI armv6   /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x375ad000 - 0x3760efff  ChatKit armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChatKit.framework/ChatKit
0x3761a000 - 0x37667fff  CoreLocation armv6  <9f16cc67cf3c2847f7c9dcc210d293d1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x37668000 - 0x3776efff  CoreData armv6  <994f884dd9e557faa8b94b2ca3cab51b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x3776f000 - 0x37770fff  SpringBoardUI armv6  <80668b013536f3c1beef01625f6ff4ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUI.framework/SpringBoardUI
0x37771000 - 0x37779fff  ProtocolBuffer armv6  <4e7169df52fbba1e3c27f207e171cecd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x3777a000 - 0x377c4fff  CoreText armv6  <20bf3a42a7e96a0312fc1776db762f1f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x37891000 - 0x37894fff  MobileInstallation armv6   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x378b4000 - 0x378f8fff  AddressBook armv6  <83aac972b7bdcf88c9f81fd73806129e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook

Answer (score 0):

You need the symbolic file in order to make any sense of this crash log. Otherwise it just points to no-name addresses within the binary.

Comment: I am new one to development so could you explain breifly  about crash log and symbolic file

Comment: The symbolic fill contains mapping between the function names in your code and the addresse these are placed in by the linker. It will be automatically generated during the build.

Comment: It is automatically created and placed in the build folder of your project and uses the extension .dysym.

Comment: @muffix i cant find that type of extension file where it is located

Comment: where it is locate that symbolic file

Answer (score 0):

You will need the .dSYM file generated during the build (located in the build directory) and the crash report. Inside your crash report find the memory addresses inside your App where the crash takes place. There should a line like

```
13  YourApp  0x0001910a 0x1000 + 98570
```

Where 0x0001910a is the crash memory address.

Then use the atos command on your command line to symbolicate the address. The syntax is like:

```
atos -arch arm -o [PATH]/YourApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/YourApp 0x0001910a
```

This will return the file, method and the line of the crash. Something like this:

```
-[YourView doSomething] (in YourApp) (YourView.m:474)
```

The atos command is part of XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an automated symbolicator.

For example: https://github.com/agentsim/Symbolicator

This great little tool is awesome and helped me a lot when I was just starting as a developer and ran into some crash logs sent from users.

Its very simple:

1. Run the Symbolicator in Xcode
2. An icon for the tool will appear in the Dock
3. Drag & Drop the crash log on the icon
4. Voila! A .symbolicated file will appear in the same directory as your crash log!

From there you can browse through the .symbolicated file and discover the exact function and line that were causing your crash.

Good luck!